# SQL merge multiple rows into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a user report that must newly assign a user's group.
Unfortunately, to achieve this I must have joined 3 tables together, which now gives me a hard time merging the groups.

I have this output at the moment:

[image: Unmerged output]

What I am trying to achieve is that the duplicate data in LastName and FirstName joins and the values in UserGroupCode merge together, separated by a comma:

[image: Merged Output]

Tried several STUFF methods, but ended up with just errors..
I will appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT
  [dbo].[User].LastName,
  [dbo].[User].FirstName,
  [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupCode
FROM [dbo].[User]
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroupUser]
   ON [dbo].[User].UserId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserId
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroup]
   ON [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserGroupId
order by 
   [LastName]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  [User].LastName,
  [User].FirstName,
  STRING_AGG([UserGroup].UserGroupCode, ',') AS Groups
FROM [dbo].[User]
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroupUser]
   ON [dbo].[User].UserId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserId
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroup]
   ON [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserGroupId
GROUP BY [User].LastName, [User].FirstName,
order by 
   [LastName]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I forgot to mention that I am doing this on a Win 2012 R2 server, which does not recognize "STRING_AGG" as a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML PATH for this use case as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  [dbo].[User].LastName,
  [dbo].[User].FirstName,
  (SELECT  [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupCode 
  FROM [dbo].[User]
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroupUser]
   ON [dbo].[User].UserId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserId
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroup]
   ON [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserGroupId
   order by 
   [LastName]
FOR XML PATH ('')
) userGroup
FROM [dbo].[User]
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroupUser]
   ON [dbo].[User].UserId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserId
JOIN [dbo].[UserGroup]
   ON [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupId = [dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserGroupId
order by 
   [LastName]
```

Comment: Hello, this outputs all [dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupCode into UserGroup column. So all users now have all user groups..

Comment: Okay, glad that XML_PATH itself worked for you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve the desired output with this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  outterSelect.LastName,
  outterSelect.FirstName,
  STUFF((
  SELECT
       ', ' + [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupCode
       FROM [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[User] innerSelect
JOIN [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroupUser]
  ON innerSelect.UserId = [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserId
JOIN [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroup]
  ON [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupId = [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserGroupId
  WHERE outterSelect.UserId = innerSelect.UserId
  FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,2,'')
  
FROM [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[User] outterSelect
JOIN [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroupUser]
  ON outterSelect.UserId = [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserId
JOIN [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroup]
  ON [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroup].UserGroupId = [FONSMediterra].[dbo].[UserGroupUser].UserGroupId
  order by [LastName]
```